# Solr 3.4 Querying GeoHash field performance issue

Tags: solr, geospatial

I'm using Solr 3.4 with an index of 20M documents with latitude longitude points for each document. There is a pre-existing indexed field that uses the solr.LatLonType called locLatLon. We are trying to compare the performance of this to the solr.GeoHashField. I added a new field to our schema that uses the GeoHash field called locLatLon_geohash that is populated by a copyField from the locLatLon field. I did a sample load of the Solr index where I loaded a few documents and I was able to search by both fields (I removed the actual solr server name)

**GeoHash query:**

```
http://solr_server:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fq={!bbox%20pt=34.1,-118.3574%20sfield=locLatLon_geohash%20d=10}
```

**Geospatial query:**

```
http://solr_server:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fq={!bbox%20pt=34.1,-118.3574%20sfield=locLatLon%20d=10}
```

On the surface these two queries should return very similar results. The geospatial query takes 62ms and returns 179k documents. The geohash query takes 34081ms and returns 121k documents. I'm not too concerned about the number of results returned (yet) as I'm concerned about the amount of time it took to generate these results.

Reading about GeoHash it seems this method of querying Solr should be very fast but it's actually very slow.

I tried debugging by adding the debugQuery=on query parameter but that doesn't tell me anything I can use without resorting to digging through the source code. Below are snippets of the Solr results with just the resultant filter query.

**GeoHash Debugging Solr output:**

```
<arr name="parsed_filter_queries">
  <str>ConstantScore(frange(ghhsin(str(locLatLon_geohash),literal(9q5cfxwybswp))):[0 TO 10.0])</str>
</arr>
```

**GeoSpatial Debugging Solr output:**

```
<arr name="parsed_filter_queries">
  <str>+locLatLon_0_coordinate:[34.01006796645071 TO 34.18993203354929] +locLatLon_1_coordinate:[-118.46600561233814 TO -118.24879438766185]</str>
</arr>
```

**QUESTION(s)**: Is there something I didn't take into account when using GeoHash type for Solr? Is there anything else I should try to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the comments to [SOLR-2155](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2155?focusedCommentId=13117350&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13117350). The attached patch was never applied and the ticket is still unresolved, but the attached zip is a plugin with the functionality so no need to actually patch SOLR. The patch is supposed to allow multiple points to be indexed on one document but it also seems to implement prefix matching the geohash for a fast bounding box search.